# How to un-select columns in OData

Tags: c#, odata

I know that we can send 'select' column queries to OData endpoints, but is it possible to send a 'hide' queries as well?

Basically, I want to select some columns without losing the open type columns.

Thanks

Comment: can you show an example? you mean you want that a $select=name,createdAt query be transformed in $select=id,name,createdAt per example? forcing the column "id" to be returned?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to hide any non-key column, but the key properties must be exposed because each entity in OData must have a key property or else there would be no way for OData to uniquely identify the given entity

Comment: Thanks, but what's the query we should send for it? (or how to specify it in C# ?)